# Proper way to avoid global variable

Tags: javascript, variables, global

Is there a proper way (ES6 friendly) to avoid using global variable in my JavaScript example ? I saw that we can use a function to wrap our code in a closure ?..

```
<textarea name="fileEdition" id="fileEdition" placeholder="Some content from a file, editable"></textarea>
<button id="saveFile">Save</button>

<script>
    const files = document.querySelector('#RandomFileListGotInPHP');
    const fileEdition = document.querySelector('#fileEdition');
    const saveButton = document.querySelector('#saveFile');

    function openFile() {
        fileEditionBackup = fileEdition.value;    
    }

    function saveFile() {
        console.log(`backup content before save in PHP: ${fileEditionBackup}`);
    }

    files.addEventListener('change', openFile);
    saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveFile);
</script>
```

Thank for the help.

Comment: IIFE is ES6 friendly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a reason against an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript):

```
(function () {

    const files = document.querySelector('#RandomFileListGotInPHP');
    const fileEdition = document.querySelector('#fileEdition');
    const saveButton = document.querySelector('#saveFile');

    function openFile() {
        fileEditionBackup = fileEdition.value;    
    }

    function saveFile() {
        console.log(`backup content before save in PHP: ${fileEditionBackup}`);
    }

    files.addEventListener('change', openFile);
    saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveFile);
})();
```

Of course, `+function(){ ... }()` or `(_=>{ ... })()` will work as well.